# Create a loop for adding content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not that experienced in javascript and totally new to the whole loop idea but I know it can save a lot of code. So I have been trying to create a loop. This is my problem: I find every variable in the first line and want to add a value to the A. I know $(this) doesn't do the trick but I can't come up with something better what works.

Basically, I want for the first variable `amount[0]` and for the second `amount[1]` and so on..

This is what I have so far..

```
$(a).each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").after( (" (" + amount[0] + ")"));
});
```

Comment: $(this) represents anchor so you can add do it directly

Comment: I know this is not really working in this case, since it goes to every variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using jQuery, not native Javascript.

The `$(selector).each` function may take two parameters: The first one is the loop counter and the second one is the callback.

(Use the counter of the `each()` method, assuming that the `amount` array has all those entries. The better aproach would be to use a conditional to check if `amount[counter]` exists)

```
$(a).each(function(counter, value) {
    //conditional to check array entry
    if (amount[counter] !== undefined) {
        $(value).find("a").after('(' + amount[counter] + ')');
    }
});
```

The `$.each()` function (without selector) may be used to iterate over arrays or an array of objects:

```
// An array
var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$.each(myArray, function (counter, value) {
    console.log(counter);
    console.log(value);
});

// An array of objects
var myArrayObject = [
    {
        one: 'foo',
        two: 'bar'
     },
     {
        one: 'another foo',
        two: 'another bar'
     }
 ];
$.each(myArrayObject, function (counter, value) {
    console.log(counter);
    console.log(value.one);
    console.log(value.two);
});
```

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more information.

Comment: Alright, I understand. But how can I say for every "a" that he finds he adds a +1 to the amount[0]

Comment: See edited answer. Use the counter of the each method, assuming that the amount array has all those entries.

Answer (score 2):

So I assume you want somthing like this:

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
    if (index >= amount.length) return; // avoind IndexOutOfBounds Exception
    $(this).after( " (" + amount[index] + ")"); // $(this) will refer to a link, in this each
});
```

After each link (`a`) you want to add a '(text_from_amount)' where text_from_amount is taken from amount array?

More about each, can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/).